# Styling scroll bar on Firefox. How to get rid of black border/outline on scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

This is the CSS I'm using to style a vertical scroll bar.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #COLOR_1;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #COLOR_2;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #COLOR_2;
  }
  scrollbar-color: ${props => "#COLOR_2" + " " + "#COLOR_1"};
  scrollbar-width: thin;
```

This is the result I expect (works on Chrome):

[image]

This is what I'm getting on Firefox:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to get rid of the black line?

It comes from the top and goes all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? just noticed in our app - I think it's a FF bug caused by setting `scrollbar-color but curious if there's an existing bug report out there.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the time to try any solutions to this, yet. So far, I'm just letting it be. Answer here if you find out something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same thing and inspired by your comment, I did some more digging.

This appears to be a [bug within Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1645782). Screenshots are attached to that bug showing a similar black outline around the scrollbar as you experienced when setting `scrollbar-color`. It appears like it's an issue on Windows Firefox only.

A fix was pushed and appears to be slated to be released in Firefox 85.

There was a comment containing a workaround: "If you set `widget.disable-native-theme-for-content=true` in `about:config` and refresh" that the OP said fixed it, but if your app is public-facing will not be much help. I tried this workaround for my site and it did not work perfectly, it removed the black outline but added a few colored pixels at the top and bottom of the scrollbar (I believe it's related to up/down buttons which are hidden by `scrollbar-width: thin`)

Another workaround is to not set `scrollbar-color` and the black outline should go away, although that is not the ideal solution when Chrome works correctly when changing scrollbar color to match the theme of your site.